# how to include template variable from another template in drupal 8

Tags: templates, drupal-8

I am using Drupal 8.I would like to include template's variables from another template.

For example, in my custom theme, there are 2 templates:

1. my_theme/templates/layout/page.html.twig (copy from core theme:classy).
2. my_theme/templates/navigation/book-navigation.html.twig (copy from core theme:classy). And prev_url is one of variables of the template.

I would like to input below code to page.html.twig so that I can print the URL of previous node, but it doesn't work:
{{ prev_url }}

How can I achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, did you enable book module? Or, in other words, does the variable works if you switch to classy theme?

Comment: Hi fadehelix, yes, I enable book module. Generally speaking, we can only use variable within its own template, my question is how we can use variable (defined for a specific template) on another template.